# How to show graphics on JPanel directly at start?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, jpanel

I want to draw a Koch Curve Snowflake in my program, its working fine so far except for 1 Problem.

I want to show a drawn Curve directly at start up, but cant get this to show ( see section in code with comment). After I press the button intended to draw a curve, it shows just fine.

What do I need to change to show something drawn on the panel before any button is pressed?

```
package fractals;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class fractalsGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel drawPanel, menuPanel;
    private JButton drawButton;
    private JTextField iterField;
    private final JLabel iterLabel = new JLabel("Iterations:");
    private final int defaultIterations = 4;

    private final double cos60 = 0.5;
    private final double sin60 = 0.5 * Math.sqrt(3);
    private final double lengthModifier = Math.sqrt(3) * 2 / 3;

    public fractalsGUI() {

        /*
         * GUI grafics setup stuff
         * 
         */

        setTitle("Koch Curve Snowflake Generator");

        drawPanel = new JPanel();
        menuPanel = new JPanel();
        drawButton = new JButton();
        iterField = new JTextField("" + defaultIterations, 2);

        this.setSize(600, 600);

        drawButton.setText("Draw Curve");
        drawButton.setActionCommand("drawCurve");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        menuPanel.add(iterLabel);
        menuPanel.add(iterField);
        menuPanel.add(drawButton);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        /*
         * draw initial Curve --- THIS DOES NOT SHOW ---
         */

        drawSegment(drawPanel.getGraphics(), new Point(200,300), new Point(400,300), 3);


        /*
         * GUI Button functions
         * 
         */

        drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("drawCurve")) {

                    int iterations = Integer.parseInt(iterField.getText());

                    if (iterations > 8)
                        iterations = 8;

                    else if (iterations < 0)
                        iterations = 0;

                    drawCurve(iterations, drawPanel.getGraphics(), new Rectangle(drawPanel.getSize()));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void drawSegment(Graphics g, Point start, Point end, int iteration) {

        // base case
        if (iteration == 0)
            g.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);

        // recursion
        else {

            Point distance = new Point((end.x - start.x) / 3, (end.y - start.y) / 3);
            Point firstThirdEnd = new Point(start.x + distance.x, start.y + distance.y);
            Point lastThirdStart = new Point(end.x - distance.x, end.y - distance.y);
            Point triangleTip = new Point(firstThirdEnd.x + (int) (distance.x * cos60 + distance.y * sin60), firstThirdEnd.y + (int) (distance.y * cos60 - distance.x * sin60));

            drawSegment(g, start, firstThirdEnd, iteration - 1);
            drawSegment(g, firstThirdEnd, triangleTip, iteration - 1);
            drawSegment(g, triangleTip, lastThirdStart, iteration - 1);
            drawSegment(g, lastThirdStart, end, iteration - 1);
        }

    }

    public void drawCurve(int iterations, Graphics g, Rectangle bounds) {

        // fill in background
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);

        double w, h;

        if (bounds.height < (int) (bounds.width * lengthModifier)) {
            // height is limiting
            h = bounds.height;
            w = h / lengthModifier;
        }

        else {
            // width is limiting
            w = bounds.width;
            h = w * lengthModifier;
        }

        int top = bounds.y + (int) ((bounds.height - h) / 2 + (h / 4));
        Point curve1start = new Point(bounds.x + (int) ((bounds.width - w) / 2), top);
        Point curve2start = new Point(bounds.x + (int) ((bounds.width + w) / 2), top);
        Point curve3start = new Point(bounds.x + (bounds.width / 2), bounds.y + (int) ((bounds.height + h) / 2));

        // draw recursion

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        drawSegment(g, curve1start, curve2start, iterations);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        drawSegment(g, curve2start, curve3start, iterations);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        drawSegment(g, curve3start, curve1start, iterations);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                fractalsGUI mainWindow = new fractalsGUI();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried just to call DrawCurve in your main after the mainWindow initialization?

Comment: Start by understanding the basic concept of how swing paints on a component. Any action that renders something onto a component should be triggered by `paintComponent`, not a constructor or whatever else. So a good point to start would be to refactor the code to match this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

after this

`drawSegment(drawPanel.getGraphics(), new Point(200,300), new Point(400,300), 3);`
call this

`drawPanel.repaint()`

Comment: This does not solve it. I still get an empty frame at first.

Comment: You could setVisible(true) after the constructor have returned, try to not extend JFrame.